# User "signing in" without specifying Contract ID

Tags: nearprotocol

Is it possible to sign in a user without specifying a contract?

From docs

```js
const signIn = () => {
  wallet.requestSignIn(
    "example-contract.testnet",     // contract requesting access --> Not include this
    "Example App",                  // optional
    "http://YOUR-URL.com/success",  // optional
    "http://YOUR-URL.com/failure"   // optional
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you skip this then `near-api-js` will create a `FullAccess` key which is how NEAR CLI handles the `near login` command